# Multi-purpose Module to update accdb records called in different userforms (using respective txtboxs)

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access, parameter-passing, adodb

I am creating an EXCEL VBA front-end system to manage a back-end Access (ACCDB) through ADODB connection.

I have been creating a single procedure to import, amend or create records in my back-end database for every userform, and i would like to tidy it and create a procedure in a Module to Call and name the objects and parameters where to get the information from.

Something like this:

In module:

```
Sub AddNewRecord(TABLE as string, INPUTFRM as 
userform, DBPATH as string, DBPASS as string, SH as worksheet)

    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim sql As String

     Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection

     cnn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & DBPATH & ";" & 
     "Jet OLEDB:Database Password=" & DBPASS

    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

     rs.Open Source:=TABLE, ActiveConnection:=cnn, _
     CursorType:=adOpenDynamic, LockType:=adLockOptimistic, _
     Options:=adCmdTable

       rs.AddNew

         For i = 1 to 10
          rs(SH.cells(1, i).value) = INPUTFRM.Controls("txtbox" & i).Value
         Next i

       rs.update
     rs.close
     cnn.close

    Set rs = Nothing
    Set cnn = Nothing

  End Sub
```

In my Userform where i input the data:

```
Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()

  Call AddNewRecord("ProjectsTable", Me.Name, ThisWorkbook.Path, "Pass1234", "Sheet1")

End Sub
```

My biggest problem is passing values from the textbox in the userform to the module. I am trying to pass the userform name to be used in the module when extracting the values in the different TextBoxes.

As in this section of the stored procedure.
Where in the first row of my sheet i have 10 field names (e.g.: ID, FirstName, LastName etc) and updated the respective fields based on the row.
The values to be updated will be contained in the 10 textboxes Userform that i Call the stored procedure.

```
 For i = 1 to 10
  rs(SH.cells(1, i).value) = INPUTFRM.Controls("txtbox" & i).Value
 Next i
```

The reason i want to make this stored procedure is that i will be using in several different forms SQL queries based on some of the inputs in those forms and would be nice to have a cleaner and smaller code.

I am sorry if it doesn't look so clear in my sample code, is that i just created this sample code as an example of what i would like to perform. 
If you guys know how to pass the Userform object value to be used in the Module or even know a workaround i would really appreciate if you'd share it.

Thank you very much,

Comment: Create new worksheet: "A". Everytime when a form submitted, store the data to the last row available in "A". In the Module, get the data from "A". Is this what you looking for?

Comment: I thought of this, it could work as a work around. Instead of getting the Userform Textboxes values through the module, to have a spreadsheet to intermediate those values. I will try it. However i still would like to know if i can pass the Textbox values to my stored procedure in the module through my Call. I want to be able to use this code for other projects, where i just need to change the variables to pass (the userform, path, pass, sheet etc).

Comment: It's not really clear what you are trying to do. First you say you are passing the userform object, then you ask about passing the userform values?

Comment: are you sure your code works as intended? you are expecting an Userform as parameter for inputform but passing Me.Name which is a string.??

Comment: Hey guys, my objective is get the information from the textboxes in varied userforms, so i can create a standard procedure to be used by other forms and manipulate the Access data. It is much easier if i have a code that creates the connections and executes the changes, and all i need to do is to pass the Userform. So i can use For i = 1 to 10 rs(Sheet.cells(1, i).value) = INPUTFRM.Controls("TxtBox" & i). In my first row of my sheet i have indexed the field values in my table. At the end i can just call it with one line in the different userforms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access doesn't have stored procedures. It has queries, but queries are limited to updating one table at a time. So that part is plain impossible.

There is one really hacky way to get stored procedure-like functionality (to update multiple tables at once) in Access: use data macros. Data macros are not intended for this purpose, and will make you unable to use the table you're setting these macro's on in a normal way. But you can use a "fake" table with data macros that updates other tables after insert, and then deletes it's own content.

You can pass a userform pretty easily, though:

In the userform:

```
Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()
  AddNewRecord "ProjectsTable", Me, ThisWorkbook.Path, "Pass1234", "Sheet1"
End Sub
```

You will have to adjust to use the actual database path.

Comment: Thank you, passing the userform as Me solved my problem. In the end i called the procedure  like the one below as a test.
{ Call AddNewRecord("PrimaryDB", Me, ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Projects.accdb", "USCIDSystem02", Projects) }. For the ones who did not understand my objective is to use some standard procedures for when i'm creating VBA projects for manipulating data in Access/SQL. It does not only make my code cleaner but also facilitate the development of other projects as i have a pre-made procedure to perform that iteration. Also thanks for providing more insight in ACCESS stored procedure